# CSS hover selector not working

Tags: css, hover, selector, parent, children

I'm encountering a strange css issue.

It's possibly because I don't use classes, but names of tags directly, but I want to learn what the problem is, so that I don't repeat it.

my HTML is like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='top'>
        <a href='href.com'>hover here..</a>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'>
        <a>..and this should change</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and what I tried with CSS:

```
.top a:hover .bottom a
{
    color:#f00; /* does not work */
}
.top a:hover .container
{
    background-color:#f00; /* does not work */
}
.top a:hover
{
    color:#f00; /* works */
}
```

So why the calls on other elements are not working?

Or is it because I'm calling parent from child?

If so, how can I make it work?

Thanks !

Comment: Your understanding of how CSS selectors work is flawed.  You can't select back up the hierarchy.

Comment: @jmoerdyk yes my first example is trying to select parent, I get it now. But what about the second? i.e. selecting the sibling ? is it impossible too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is wrong, your forgot commas:

```
.top a:hover, .bottom a:hover
{
    color:#f00;
}
.top a:hover, .container:hover /* Comma was missing here */
{
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: If I add commas, .bottom a and .container will always be #f00, am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't get that you want it only on hover. I've updated should be fine now. Please try to explain better what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to change .bottom, when .top a is hovered.

Comment: Nope. I think you'll have to use javascript for that. especially for the parent part.

Answer (score 2):

A year late, but for anyone who stumbles here, use the following as the css:

```
.top:hover ~ .bottom {color: red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xb62A/